# Check name in AD before submit in create view MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

you can say that I'm new in C# MVC and having some problems, been researching a lot, and this is my first topic here.

I'm developing an application that uses data of active directory. I have a table User that import Data from AD.
here is my controller create code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher();
            directorySearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + user.IdUser + "))";
            SearchResult results = directorySearch.FindOne(); 
             if (results != null)
            {
                if (results.Properties.Contains("mail")) //E-mail
                  {
                      user.E_mail = results.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
                  }
               else
                  {
                     user.E_mail = string.Empty;
                  }
                if (results.Properties.Contains("c")) //Country
                {
                    user.Country = results.Properties["c"][0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    user.Country = string.Empty;
                }


            }

            db.User.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CompanyCode = new SelectList(db.Company, "CompanyCode", "CompanyName", user.CompanyCode);
        ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(db.Country, "CountryName", "CountryName", user.Country);
        return View(user);
    }`
```

this is some of my create view code:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdUser)

    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdUser)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdUser)
```

what I want to do is check in the AD if the user really exists with a function and return the value to the IdUser field but before click the submit, just like a check names.

A solution that I was thinking of,
in the view just put a button:

```
        <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Check" onClick="CheckFunction(model.IdUser)" />
    </p>
```

and the function is something like:

```
        public string CheckFunction(string Id)
    {
            DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher();
            directorySearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" + Id + "))";
            SearchResult results = directorySearch.FindOne();
            if (results != null)
            {
                return Id;
            }
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

but the problem is that I dont know how to set the Id string returned in Function to the model.IdUser field.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: do an ajax jquery call to the controller.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359204/asp-net-mvc-4-passing-object-variable-through-actionlink/19360998#19360998.  in the success you can set the result to the id field using $('.IdUser').val(result.id) or whatever you pass back

Comment: Don't know if I understand, could you explain more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to put a class on your button (class="btnSave" for the code below)

```
$('.btnSave').on('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("CheckFunction", "Controller"))',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            //this is the id that is passed.  change @Model.Id to whatever id you want sent
            Id: '@Model.Id'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.Success){
                //if this is a submit button it will do a post back.  If just a button you can set fields with the returned data or alert, etc
                $('.fieldId').val(result.Id);
            }else{
                //e.preventDefault() will stop the submit button from submitting if failed is returned
                e.preventDefault();
                //do something for failure (alert or something)
            }
        }
    });
});
```

then change your controller to return json for success or failure.  here is an example for that [json success and fail response in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880285/json-success-and-fail-response-in-mvc)